# Does Windows provide a monotonically increasing clock to applications

Tags: windows, time, timer

This question is inspired by [Does Linux provide a monotonically increasing clock to applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211055/does-linux-provide-a-monotonically-increasing-clock-to-applications).

Maybe I should be more precise:
I'm looking for a clock function which is [strictly increasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), thus never returning the same value, independant how quick two calls follow each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [`GetTickCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) does this. If you want a higher fidelity counter, [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) is also available. Neither of these counters depend on the time of day.

Comment: Should change your link to GetTickCount64() -- from your link, the return value of GTC wraps after about 50 days.

Comment: GetTickCount64() is only available on Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008.

Comment: As long as you can rely on being called at least once a month or so, you can cobble together a GetTickCount64() wrapper around GetTickCount().

Comment: Be careful with QueryPerformanceCounter because it can leap forward unexpectedly by several seconds, so you have to compare it constantly with GetTickCount: [Microsoft KB274323](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274323/en-gb).

Comment: The above does not answer the (edited) original question since none of the suggestions provide a _strictly increasing_ clock.

Comment: @TylerStreeter That KB isn't available anymore. MS std::chrono::steady_clock uses QPC timers